# Weird exception in destructor that uses datetime strftime method

Tags: python-3.x, destructor

my __del_ method called other method that closes the connection to the hardware.

In the method that close the connection I use the following line (actually called from get_timedate_plus_file_string method as seen in the Traceback):

```
x =  ("ID{:02} {} -".format(print_id_num,datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

And I get the following error:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method temp_class.__del__ of
<drv_temp_class.c_temp_class object at 0x0000000007DF8A58>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\1\drv_temp_class.py", line 323, in __del__
  File "D:\1\drv_temp_class.py", line 309, in close_connection
  File "D:\1\global_def.py", line 162, in print_msg
  File "D:\1\global_def.py", line 105, in get_timedate_plus_file_string
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 887, in _find_spec
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I debug the issue to the strftime method , meaning that removing the formatting of strftime , all is working.

In addition , I replaced the use of datetime.datetime in time.localtime and all is working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `__del__` method can be invoked during interpreter shutdown, possibly after modules (e.g. datetime) have already been cleaned up (which is what seems to be happening in your case). It's generally better to use a context manager for resources that have to be cleaned up, so that the cleanup code happens before the interpreter starts tearing everything down.

Comment: I know that is better to use explicit close method that close all resources. I just saw that its not the case in some of my code and i will fix it. According to your answer , the fact that it working for me with time.localtime can be a pure chance?